# Receiving data from other Android apps only works once

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to develop a simple app, which receives text from other android Apps and then open a browser.

I have implemented it as described in the documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

It works, but only once.
The first time a text is shared from an other App, the browser is opened correctly.
But the second time only my app is opened, but not the browser.

What could be the reason for this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Get the intent that started this activity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // Get the action of the intent
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // Get the type of intent (Text or Image)
        String type = intent.getType();
        // When Intent's action is 'ACTION+SEND' and Type is not null
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            // When tyoe is 'text/plain'
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
            }
        }

    }

    private void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
        // Get the text from intent
        String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if (sharedText != null) {
            openBrowser(sharedText);
        }

    }

    private void openBrowser(String text) {

            Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://example.com/api.php?text=" + text));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openBrowser` method is called from the `handleSendText` method witch it is on the `onCreate` method , second time you open your app ( If you didnt press the back button ) your app  is already created ! so the code will never execute.

Please check the life cycle of an android activity below

[image: Android Activity life cycle]

You may edit your code and call the `openBrowser` method on the `onResume` method or just make a button to call the method `openBrowser` Oncliking the button.